# Is it possible to store a variable in a list in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put the following variables in a list by grouping them into a class or making them a global variable...
How can I put it on the list?
Is it possible to put these variables in a list?

The button below is a favorite variable that is saved locally.
It changes frequently.

ex.favorite[index]

```
bool favoriteButton_0_01_01 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_02 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_03 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_04 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_05 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_06 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_07 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_08 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_09 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_10 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_11 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_12 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_13 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_14 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_15 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_16 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_17 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_18 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_19 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_20 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_21 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_22 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_23 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_24 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_25 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_26 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_27 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_28 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_29 = false;
bool favoriteButton_0_01_30 = false;
```

Comment: Try using map:  `Map<String, bool> favorites = {}`

Comment: In this case, it cannot be loaded with [index].
I need to be able to load the value by favorite[index]!
(This is because it will be used by adding + and - to the index when turning to the next page.)

Comment: [Have you tried using a list?](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists)

Comment: Isn't this a string output?

Answer (score 1):

[Use a `List`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists)

```dart
List<bool> favoriteButtons = [
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
  false,
];
```

Or better yet:

```dart
List<bool> favoriteButtons = List.filled(30, false);
```

Use it like:

```dart
var buttonValue = favoriteButtons[3]; // Or whatever index
```

Comment: How could it be this simple... I was stupid and you were a genius...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Map` as suggested by [שו אוהב אותך](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4758255/%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%94%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9A)
and then use `favorites.values.toList()[index]`

```
Map<String, bool> favorites = {
            'favoriteButton_0_01_01': false,
            'favoriteButton_0_01_02': false
          };
          print(favorites.values.toList()[0]);
```

Comment: Why on earth would they want to use a `Map` and then convert it into a `List` when they could just use a `List` in the first place?

Comment: Just in case he wants to preserve the variable names. If not, obviously it makes no sense to use a map and then convert it to a list.

Comment: favorites.values.toList()[0] = prefs.getBool('_favoriteButton_0_01_01')!;
When using , the value is not stored in the list value.

Comment: This doesn't preserve a variable name. It just uses it arbitrarily as a string key. There is no connection whatsoever between the old variable names and the keys of this map. And converting the map to a list breaks any relationship with the map itself. This approach is textbook overcomplication.

Comment: A `List<bool>` can be used if all the `index` is always fixed. But it's useless when the related `buttons` is moved and the `bool` status need to be restored regardless of the position. Hence the `Map` is used.

Comment: @Abion obviously it does not reserve a variable name but might be used for reference.

Comment: @eno2 You have to update the map using the string key and use favorites.values.toList() only when accessing values using index.

Comment: A reference to what? An arbitrary ex-variable name with no context and now has to be remembered and entered exactly right without any compile-time safety whatsoever or a null exception will crash the app? It's a sloppy design that is a clear source of unnecessary complexity and random runtime errors.

Comment: Yes true, I think I haven't really understood the requirement here.